# synergy register hotkey using text config

Tags: python, c++

I want to register the hotkey
So, I added key types

> 1. key_types.h

```
 static const KeyID     kKeyHangul = 0xEF31;    /* Zenkaku/Hankaku */ //asmera modify to 0xef31 from 0xef26
```

> 2. key_types.cpp

```
keyNameMap[][]
{ "Hangul",         kKeyHangul }
```

> 3. MSWindowsKeyState.cpp

```
    /* 0x015 */ { kKeyHangul },
    /* 0x115 */ { kKeyHangul },
```

> and config script is

```
section: screens
    server:
    client1:
end

section: aliases
    server:
        YOO-Lab
    client1:
        YOO-SURFACE
end

section: links
#   server:
#       down = client1
#   client:
#       up = server
end

section: options
    screenSaverSync = false
    keystroke(control+1) = switchToScreen(server)
    keystroke(control+2) = switchToScreen(client1)
#?? keystroke(ctrl+alt+space) = Hangul
end
```

I want to know how to convert (Ctrl+Alt+Space) to (Hangul)key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me - <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Check out this reference for more keys: https://github.com/symless/synergy/blob/master/src/lib/synergy/key_types.cpp

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have 
some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the 
target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.